# When I add html code to the variable, it shows as Nan

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nan

```
 var test = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < controlResponse.classifications.length; i++) {
        test+='<div role="option" aria-checked="false" class="select item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">' + controlResponse.classifications[i].name + ' </span></div>';

    }
   
    for (var i = 0; i < controlResponse.fileList.length; i++) {

        var htmlCode='<div class="row">                                                                                                                                                      '+
         '   <div class= "ten wide computer sixteen wide mobile ten wide tablet column">                                                                                                    '+
         '   <h5 class="ui header">                                                                                                                                                          '+
         '       <i aria-hidden="true" class="file word outline large icon fa-fw"></i>                                                                                                       '+
         '       <div class="content">outlook_testler.docx</div>                                                                                                                             '+
         '   </h5>                                                                                                                                                                           '+
         '       </div > <div class="six wide computer sixteen wide mobile six wide tablet column">                                                                                          '+
         '       <div role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" class="ui selection dropdown" tabindex="0" style="float: right;">                                                                 '+
         '           <div aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite" role="alert" class="divider default text">Classification</div><i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>               '+
            '           <div class="menu transition classifications">                                                                                                                      ' +
            +test+
            '           </div>                                                                                                                                                                  ' +
         '   </div>                                                                                                                                                                      '+
         '   </div>                                                                                                                                                                          '+
            '   </div>';
        $("#classificationModalList").append(htmlCode);

         
    }
```

When I add html code to the variable, it shows as NaN.
I add select item html codes to test variable then I added test variable inside htmlCode variable
then I added test variable inside htmlCode variable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#template_literals

Comment: Before the `+test+` you have an additional `+` at the end of the previous line. The second one is seen as a [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus). Remove one of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining all the strings using `+` and `'` you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Here I combined it with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) – that is more readable too.

```js
/* test data */
const controlResponse = {};
controlResponse.classifications = [{name:'class01'},{name:'class02'}];
controlResponse.fileList = ['file01', 'file02'];

var test = controlResponse.classifications.map(classification => {
  return `<div role="option" aria-checked="false" class="select item" style="pointer-events: all;">
            <span class="text">${classification.name}</span>
          </div>`;
}).join('');

var htmlCode = controlResponse.fileList.map(file => {
  return `<div class="row">
            <div class="ten wide computer sixteen wide mobile ten wide tablet column">
              <h5 class="ui header">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="file word outline large icon fa-fw"></i>
                <div class="content">outlook_testler.docx</div>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="six wide computer sixteen wide mobile six wide tablet column">
              <div role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" class="ui selection dropdown" tabindex="0" style="float: right;">
                <div aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite" role="alert" class="divider default text">Classification</div>
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="menu transition classifications">${test}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>`;
}).join('');

$("#classificationModalList").append(htmlCode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="classificationModalList"></div>
```